# how to customize Visual Studio 2022 theme

Tags: visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio 2022 and the purple line at the top is damaging my eyes

[image]

I know that I have to change it in font and color setting but there is more option, which one will change this color

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you want to try [Visual Studio Color Theme Designer 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=idex.colorthemedesigner2022)

Or install [VS2019 dark theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.DarkTheme2019)

And additionally report it to http://developercommunity.visualstudio.com as a problem, to make the default theme good.